# Drupal 7 module for Password Complexity Rules

Tags: users

For a Drupal 7 site the customer would like to implement the following (see at bottom) Password Complexity Rules.  Which of the below rules are possible to implement and what would be the best module to use for these rules?

---

- The password must be at least 12 characters (network enforced)
- The password must contain both upper and lower case characters: a-z, A-Z (network enforced.)
- The password must contain numbers and punctuation characters as well as letters: 0-9, !#$%^&*()_+|~=`{}[]:";'<>?,./@ (network enforced.)
- The password should not be or contain a word in a dictionary
- The password should not be a common usage word, such as:

  - Names of family, pets, friends, co-workers, fantasy characters, or sport teams
  - Birthdays or other personal information, such as addresses and phone numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can implement this bit of the rules

> The password must contain both upper and lower case characters: a-z,
>   A-Z (network enforced.) · The password must contain numbers and
>   punctuation characters as well as letters: 0-9,
>   !#$%^&*()_+|~=`{}[]:";'<>?,./@

anything extra is pushing it, plus it is difficult to enforce

You can use this module [Password policy](https://drupal.org/project/password_policy) for implementing it

> This module provides a way to specify a certain level of password
>   complexity (aka. "password hardening") for user passwords on a system
>   by defining a password policy.

Comment: How can we implement this "The password should not be or contain a word in a dictionary" ?